# SQL ID value auto move up

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which an auto-increment ID column. I want my database to automatically change the ID value so there is always an ID value of 1.


For example:

```
ID Firstname Lastname

1  John      Smith
2  Charlie   Jacobs
3  Jason     young
```

I want it so that if I delete row ID 1 then row ID 2 changes to ID 1 and row ID 3 changes to ID 2. Like this:

```
ID Firstname Lastname

1  Charlie   Jacobs
2  Jason     young
```

I want to be able to then add names after which would carry on from ID 3. Preferably I was wondering if there was a setting in SQL that can do this automatically. If this isn't possible then a PHP script would be the second best thing.

Comment: The only question is - **why**?

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. What about foreign keys? Why do you care what value is in the identity???

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  The identifier should *never* change once a record is written.

Comment: Why would you want this to be in the database?, and which database engine are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Why?  AUtoincrements are there only to provide uniqueness to each row.  You should assign no more meaning to the value than that.

Comment: Sure, define a trigger to catch any deletes and update a record to become id=1, but DON'T do this. IDs are supposed to be immutable. you're just asking for trouble down the line.

Comment: If you want sequential numbers then look into using ROW_NUMBER at run time. Changing the value of an identity is going to cause you nothing but headaches. Aside from RI issues you would constantly have to be reseeding the identity. Just don't this.

Comment: If you need to do this, then add a separate sort order column (or whatever you want to name it). Moving IDs around will cause you lots of headaches, and is a very strange thing to do anyway.

Comment: What you're looking for is a ranking column.  Leave the auto increment and add a new column called "rank".  It seems like what you're looking to have is an ordering of records by when they were added to the table, so you could potentially use a timestamp in the rank column and just order them by time.  That way, no matter what records get deleted, you can always order them by when they were added to the table.

Comment: I'm with Sean: create a view with ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) to get a sequential number and leave the identity value as it is. The ROW_NUMBER() approach wouldn't even create a "huge" amount of overhead, since the data are already in the order required.

Comment: If you haven't guessed it by now: don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a right thing to do. Why do you want to do that? This would mess up your primary key values. So don't do it. Coming to the solution

If you are displaying this inside a form, just generate a row number for each row in your select statement. It will not have any gaps in between. [MYSQL Generating Row Numbers](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/)

```
SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number,db_names FROM mysql_testing, 
(SELECT @row_number:=0) AS t
ORDER BY db_names;
```